# Is it possible to use context menu with QSystemTrayIcon under Windows Mobile/CE?

Tags: qt, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I created tray icon with context menu and attached its activated signal to slot in my dialog:

```
trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);
trayIconMenu->addAction(showAction);
trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/gear.png"));
trayIcon->show();
trayIcon->showMessage(tr("SSTRNL-B"),tr("Message from tray icon!"));

QObject::connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
                 this,   SLOT(trayactivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
```

My slot is called when I click on tray icon. So everything is going right except I can not see context menu attached to QSystemTrayIcon.

In desktop systems we can use right-click on tray icon to see its context menu. But what am I supposed to do in Windows mobile/CE to see context menu?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason==QSystemTrayIcon::Context` in your `SLOT`. May be as you are using mobile App, click pattern for `contextmenu` might be different from General OS.

Ok if it is `QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger`, call `trayIcon->contextMenu()->popup(QPoint&)` in your SLOT, where QPoint is location of trayIcon.That would do.

Comment: In my case slot is called with reason == QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger. I am almost sure click pattern is different. Unfortunately i don't know if it is possible to activate context menu from system tray icon in windows mobile.

Comment: If reason is QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger, Why would you expect to popup context menu? Try out different click patterns and I am sure you will findout click pattern corresponding to QSystemTrayIcon::context eventually.

Comment: What do you mean saying "different click patterns"? I tried simple click (generates QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger) and double click (generates QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick). What else click patterns can i try?

Comment: Any other buttons or function keys. Anyway try out the method i just specified.

Comment: Your method could work if i have QPoint with trayIcon's location. Unfortunately trayIcon->geometry() returns QRect with topleft coords (0,0) and downright coords (-1,-1).

Comment: I not found a way to generate QSystemTrayIcon::Context. I debug my application using device emulator which emulates touchscreen and has not many buttons. I tried to press every button with no success.

Comment: geometry returns screen co-ordinate, convert it to client co-ordinate[ScreenTocClient(Qpoint)](don't sure this would work, I am suggesting this as you are developing mobile app). If that  \doesn't work, You know the position of trayicon.You might be placing it somehow, somewere. Try using that position for popping up the context-menu.

Comment: QSystemTrayIcon gives us no way to specify position of tray icon.

Comment: To use ScreenToClient i need some HWND. This is not portable. And QSystemTrayIcon has no HWND property.